# how to find latitude and longitude of a place in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, gps

how to find latitude and longitude of a address in Wp7

**ex :**

If I give the location name : "New York" then i want get its latitude and longitude.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

Class for deserializing the json string

```
public class PlaceInfo
{
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string licence { get; set; }
    public string osm_type { get; set; }
    public string osm_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> boundingbox { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lon { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string @class { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public double importance { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code to get the informations from the website: 
Format is JSON, i'm using the json serializor of c#

using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string jsonString = webClient.DownloadString("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city=%22new%20york%22&format=json");

//load into memorystream
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
{
    //parse
    var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PlaceInfo[]));
    PlaceInfo[] obj = (PlaceInfo[])ser.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

the array obj has now all places which where found with that name. for example jsut take the first place which was found obj[0].lon and obj[0].lat

Answer (score 2):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string xml = webClient.DownloadString("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city=%22new%20york%22&format=xml");
```

Comment: have you used this before to get latitude and langitude ??

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use openstreetmaps:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city=%22new%20york%22&format=json

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city="---cityname---"&countrycodes="---CountryCode---"&limit=2&format=json

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

you can get the result as json or xml

Comment: am very new to WP7 how to call this url from c#